# camera control in iphone app

Tags: iphone, camera

I have created a app which consist of camera option.In that camera view, I have added a help button which should display in that camera view when the user about to take a pic.but it should hide after the user took his photo.I need oly the camera controls and the preview of photo,not that help button.where should I write function for this.I am finding very hard to do this.waiting for the reply.